# While saving .csv to database error occured:-' list index out of range '

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
def import_db(request):
    f=open('product.csv','r')
    for row in f:
      row =  row.split('!')
      tmp = AdminProduct.objects.create()

      tmp.id = row[0]
      tmp.productname = row[1]
      tmp.barcode = row[2]
      tmp.company = row[3]
      tmp.size = row[4]
      tmp.price = row[5]
      tmp.description = row[6]
      tmp.category = row[7]
      tmp.subcategory = row[8]
      tmp.product_tag = row[9]
      tmp.image = row[10]
      tmp.save()

    f.close()
```

This error(list index out of range) occured while saving .csv file into database.

Comment: Why don't you use the actual `csv` library, which is specifically intended for reading CSV files?

Comment: Will try it once the below solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure every line in your file results 11 words after split 
  `row =  row.split('!')`
or add a condition before assigning values to tmp object

```
if len(row)==11:
     #assign vlaues here & save
```

Comment: csv file is uploaded,with empty values

Comment: Please check , how many words you are getting after each split. Better you take the count of words after split, and create a dictionary , later you can access using the keys while assigning to tmp object, u can use dictionary's get method.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should use a proper csv library as mentioned in the comments

2) You should be careful about data types loaded from your CSV

To answer your question given the little amount of info we have, I'd say you should use `.split(",")` and not `.split("!")`

Comment: I haven't found a proper guide to upload .csv file in Django. :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv #will get csv from python

def import_db(request):
    with open('product.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    row1=True   #will skip your first row and mismatching of variable type
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row1:
            row1 = False
            continue

        tmp = AdminProduct.objects.create(
             id          = row[0],
             productname = row[1],
             barcode     = row[2],
             company     = row[3],
             size        = row[4],
             price       = row[5],
             description = row[6],
             category    = row[7],
             subcategory = row[8],
             product_tag = row[9],
             image       = row[10],
             )
    return redirect('/somewhere/')
```

when you upload your .csv the logic behind it remains the same as on web, what you need to do check is the type of the data your .csv data you want to insert and the matching columns the database table have.They both must be same.
Also it's better to use some kind of library for the import-export of .csv file.
Hope this helps..!